# How to change the gcc version on the Mac

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

Recently, I want to use a database which need gcc/g++ +4.3 in the Mac. the default gcc version is 4.2.1, like this:

[image]

So I use the brew to install the latest gcc 5.3:

[image]

But how to change the gcc version to the 5.3?

Comment: The default version of GCC isn't actually what you think it is. Take a closer look at the `gcc -v` output... Notice how it says "Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)"? That means you're really running Clang instead and not GCC. Also try e.g. `gcc-5` or `gcc-5.3`.